# Does passing many parameters from constructor slows down the program?

Tags: java, performance

I have been desigining classes in following way:

```
public class add{
      private int firstEntry;
      private int secondEntry;

      public add(int a , int b){
          this.firstEntry= a;
          this.secondEntry=b
      }

      public int makeAddition(){
          return firstEntry+secondEntry;
      }

}
```

Does this pattern of program slows down program in java?

Comment: I don't think method name and parameters will cause performance issues . It could increase the size of the file .

Comment: Compared to what? And also, no.

Comment: If your having speed issues, profile the app and find the bottle necks, don't second guess your code

Answer (score 6):

First off - 2 parameters isn't a lot! And secondly, no it won't slow down the program - what "faster" alternative would you use?

Focus on designing good, readable code and then if (and only if) you need to optimise, you can do that later. The ability to design good, readable code is much more important, and at this stage that's what you should be focusing on.

If you have loads of parameters (you say 15, which is a lot) then potentially look into the [builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html). Nothing to do with performance, but doing things this way is generally better when you have a large amount of parameters in your constructor since it means when someone calls it, they can clearly see what parameter they're referencing each time.

Comment: in fact there are many parameters which reaches upto 15. Now, I have issue on speed of program.

Comment: @thetna See edit - no speed difference at all, but the builder pattern may be a better alternative for other reasons.

Comment: +1 for builder pattern. Also note, that adding extra parameter to them constructor/method call can potentially be a performance issue, but 2 parameters is not issue.

Answer (score 3):

Passing many parameters from constructor doesn't slow down the program, it slows down the programmer that needs to read it.

Answer (score 0):

passing 2 parameters isn't very much, it won't slow down the program very much. as an alternative to that code, you could have:

```
public class add{
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```